# Creating multiple child processes

Tags: python, python-3.x, fork

I have the next function:

`func` multiplies 5 by x and prints.

```
import os, time
import sys

x = 1

try:
    pid=os.fork()
    if pid == 0:
        func()
    else:
        time.sleep(5)
    print(x)

#except error......
```

Output:

```
5 (child)
sleep(5) (parent)
1
```

How I can create multiple N child processes using `fork()`, since this just creates one?

Comment: Maybe use `fork()` more than once? But why not use https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html or https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html instead?

Comment: The `ProcessPoolExecutor` seems to be suitable for such tasks: https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor

Comment: *os.fork()* isn't 100% portable. I would avoid that and consider either multiprocessing or multithreading depending on your actual use-case